# .NET CF mobile device application - best methodology to handle potential offline-ness?

Tags: database, web-services, windows-mobile, compact-framework, offline

I'm building a mobile application in VB.NET (compact framework), and I'm wondering what the best way to approach the potential offline interactions on the device. Basically, the devices have cellular and 802.11, but may still be offline (where there's poor reception, etc). A driver will scan boxes as they leave his truck, and I want to update the new location - immediately if there's network signal, or queued if it's offline and handled later. It made me think, though, about how to handle offline-ness in general.

- Do I cache as much data to the device as I can so that I use it if it's offline - Essentially, each device would have a copy of the (relevant) production data on it? Or is it better to disable certain functionality when it's offline, so as to avoid the headache of synchronization later? I know this is a pretty specific question that depends on my app, but I'm curious to see if others have taken this route.
- Do I build the application itself to act as though it's always offline, submitting everything to a local queue of sorts that's owned by a local class (essentially abstracting away the online/offline thing), and then have the class submit things to the server as it can? What about data lookups - how can those be handled in a "Semi-live" fashion?
- Or should I have the application attempt to submit requests to the server directly, in real-time, and handle it if it itself request fails? I can see a potential problem of making the user wait for the timeout, but is this the most reliable way to do it?

I'm not looking for a specific solution, but really just stories of how developers accomplish this with the smoothest user experience possible, with a link to a how-to or heres-what-to-consider or something like that. Thanks for your pointers on this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can't give you a definitive answer because there is no "right" answer that fits all usage scenarios.  For example if you're using SQL Server on the back end and SQL CE locally, you could always set up merge replication and have the data engine handle all of this for you.  That's pretty clean.  Using the offline application block might solve it.  Using store and forward might be an option.

You could store locally and then roll your own synchronization with a direct connection, web service of WCF service used when a network is detected. You could use MSMQ for delivery.

What you have to think about is not what the "right" way is, but how your implementation will affect application usability.  If you disable features due to lack of connectivity, is the app still usable?  If you have stale data, is that a problem?  Maybe some critical data needs to be transferred when you have GSM/GPRS (which typically isn't free) and more would be done when you have 802.11.  Maybe you can run all day with lookup tables pulled down in the morning and upload only transactions, with the device tracking what changes it's made.

Basically it really depends on how it's used, the nature of the data, the importance of data transactions between fielded devices, the effect of data latency, and probably other factors I can't think of offhand.

So the first step is to determine how the app needs to be used, *then* determine the infrastructure and architecture to provide the connectivity and data access required.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it myself, but have you looked into the "store and forward" capabilities of the CF? It may suit your needs.  I believe it uses an Exchange mailbox as a message queue to send SOAP packets to and from the device.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to approach this is to always work offline, then use message queues to handle  sending changes to and from the device. When the driver marks something as delivered, for example, update the item as delivered in your local store and also place a message in an outgoing queue to tell the server it's been delivered. When the connection is up, send any queued items back to the server and get any messages that have been queued up from the server.